How to quickly measure the rise time of a signal represented inside a numpy array
I have a numpy array called voltage which is supposed to go from 0 to 1, in 1ps time steps. Thing is some times it may not go from 0 to 1, it might rise from zero and come back to 1.
I want to measure the rise time, time taken to go from 0 to 0.9, if the voltage is coming back to 0 or close to zero, lets say below 0.5, I want to mark it as a failure by marking rise time as -1.
I can do this by looking at the whole array elements 1 by 1, I want to know if there is a faster way to do this, as I need to do this fro several thousand arrays.

Numpy is not really designed for signal processing and time series. For signal processing, there is Scipy. IDK for time series. You can iterate over Numpy array or use scan-based approach to do this in a vectorized way but is is often sub-optimal and not actually always possible. If you do not care about performance, then writing a loop doing what you want should be pretty simple. By the way, note you should share what you tried so far / your research effort.

Can you give an example of one of these voltage arrays, and give the expected output?

You can find rise time by finding the pulse starts and then determining the lower and upper values it reaches and finding the times signal reached those, and taking the difference.

Find pulse start using a derivative and searching for regions of high value
Find the beginning of the rise by gradient descent to a plateau
Find the end of the rise by gradient ascent to a plateau

The algorithm I provide here under-estimates rise time by about 15% pretty consistently, which could be corrected for, but honestly, when I look at the graph, I think that's about as accurate as you can do anyways; not even by hand do I think I would be much more accurate with the sample data I am using.
find_pulses is the important function here, everything else is testing code and boilerplate, and will probably require some modification to meet your needs.
import dataclasses
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Pulse:
    # A convenience function for generating and comparing pulses
    t: float
    pw: float
    power: float
    rise_time: float
    fall_time: float

    def sample(self, t: float) -> float:
        # Generic pulse sampling function, can be adjusted to match some other shaped pulse
        #   but more likely unused if samples are already available
        if t < self.t - self.rise_time:
            # Before the pulse rise time starts
            return 0.0
        if t > self.t + self.pw + self.fall_time:
            # After the pulse fall time ends
            return 0.0
        if t < self.t:
            # During pulse rise time
            real_t = t - (self.t - self.rise_time)
            return self.power * (1 - (real_t / self.rise_time - 1) ** 2)
        if t < self.t + self.pw:
            # During full power of pulse
            return self.power
        else:
            # During pulse fall time
            real_t = t - (self.t + self.pw)
            return self.power * (1 - (real_t / self.fall_time) ** 2)

    def diff_frac(self, other) -> list[float]:
        # This function calculates the fractional difference between this pulse and another
        return [
            -(self.t - other.t) / self.pw,
            -(self.pw - other.pw) / self.pw,
            -(self.power - other.power) / self.power,
            -(self.rise_time - other.rise_time) / self.rise_time,
            -(self.fall_time - other.fall_time) / self.fall_time,
        ]


def make_data(pulses: list[Pulse], duration: float, points: int, rng: np.random.Generator, noise: float):
    # Mock up some data to analyze by sampling a series of pulses
    data_x = np.linspace(0, duration, points)
    data_y = rng.random(data_x.shape) * noise
    for xi, x in enumerate(data_x):
        for pulse in pulses:
            data_y[xi] += pulse.sample(x)
    return data_x, data_y


def find_pulses(data_x: np.array, data_y: np.array, minimum_pw: float):
    amp_threshold = 0.05

    # Use a sliding window to approximate the derivative
    #   Use averaged windows to build in some noise resistance
    amp_deriv = np.zeros(shape=data_x.shape)
    xend = 0
    for xstart in range(len(data_x)):
        # Find the endpoint that covers the desired window - minimum_pw
        while data_x[xend] < data_x[xstart] + minimum_pw and xend < len(data_x) - 1:
            xend += 1
        # If there isn't enough data to continue, stop processing
        if data_x[xend] - data_x[xstart] < minimum_pw / 2:
            break
        # Calculate the window as half the total range (minimum_pw)
        window = (xend - xstart) // 2
        # If the window is 0 length, skip this iteration
        if not window:
            continue
        # Make sure both halves are the same length
        xmid = xstart + window
        xend = xstart + 2 * window
        # Calculate the derivative as the difference of the right and left halves of the window
        left_sum = np.sum(data_y[xstart: xmid])
        right_sum = np.sum(data_y[xmid: xend])
        amp_dif = (right_sum - left_sum) / window
        # Add this value to the output array
        amp_deriv[xmid] = amp_dif

    # scipy already has a built-in function for peak finding which works quite well
    #   peaks_pos are rising edges, peaks_neg are falling edges
    find_peaks_args = {
        'height': 0,
        'prominence': amp_threshold * max(amp_deriv),
        'distance': minimum_pw // (data_x[1] - data_x[0])
    }
    peaks_pos, _ = scipy.signal.find_peaks(amp_deriv, **find_peaks_args)
    peaks_neg, _ = scipy.signal.find_peaks(-amp_deriv, **find_peaks_args)

    # Process the rising edges (map them to falling edges later)
    pulse_starts = []
    rise_times = []
    for leading_edge in sorted(peaks_pos):
        # This is the total change and will be used to bracket the rising edge
        rise_mag = amp_deriv[leading_edge]
        left_edge = right_edge = leading_edge
        # Detect the left edge as 99% of the way to minimum
        while left_edge and amp_deriv[left_edge] > rise_mag * 0.01:
            left_edge -= 1
        # Detect the right edge as 99% of the way to maximum
        while right_edge < len(amp_deriv) - 1 and amp_deriv[right_edge] > rise_mag * 0.01:
            right_edge += 1
        # Find the range before the peak rise and calculate the threshold to consider the start
        left_range = np.max(data_y[left_edge: leading_edge]) - np.min(data_y[left_edge: leading_edge])
        left_threshold = np.min(data_y[left_edge: leading_edge]) + amp_threshold * left_range
        # Find the range after the peak rise and calculate the threshold to consider the end
        right_range = np.max(data_y[leading_edge: right_edge]) - np.min(data_y[leading_edge: right_edge])
        right_threshold = np.max(data_y[leading_edge: right_edge]) - amp_threshold * right_range
        # Slide the edges until the threshold is met and then cut it off
        inner_left = leading_edge
        while inner_left and data_y[inner_left] > left_threshold:
            inner_left -= 1
        inner_right = leading_edge
        while inner_right < len(data_y) - 1 and data_y[inner_right] < right_threshold:
            inner_right += 1
        # Record inner_left as the start of the rise time, inner_right as the start of the full power pulse
        rise_times.append(inner_left)
        pulse_starts.append(inner_right)

    # Repeat for the falling edge
    pulse_ends = []
    fall_times = []
    for falling_edge in sorted(peaks_neg):
        fall_mag = amp_deriv[falling_edge]
        left_edge = right_edge = falling_edge
        while left_edge and amp_deriv[left_edge] < fall_mag * 0.01:
            left_edge -= 1
        while right_edge < len(amp_deriv) - 1 and amp_deriv[right_edge] < fall_mag * 0.01:
            right_edge += 1

        left_range = np.max(data_y[left_edge: falling_edge]) - np.min(data_y[left_edge: falling_edge])
        left_threshold = np.max(data_y[left_edge: falling_edge]) - amp_threshold * left_range

        right_range = np.max(data_y[falling_edge: right_edge]) - np.min(data_y[falling_edge: right_edge])
        right_threshold = np.min(data_y[falling_edge: right_edge]) + amp_threshold * right_range

        inner_left = falling_edge
        while inner_left and data_y[inner_left] < left_threshold:
            inner_left -= 1
        inner_right = falling_edge
        while inner_right < len(data_y) - 1 and data_y[inner_right] > right_threshold:
            inner_right += 1

        fall_times.append(inner_right)
        pulse_ends.append(inner_left)

    # For each pulse start find an appropriate pulse end and create a pulse from those
    pulses = []
    for pulse_start, pulse_rise_time in zip(pulse_starts, rise_times):

        pulse_end = pulse_start
        pulse_fall_time = None
        # Find the first pulse_end after the pulse_start
        for i, pulse_end in enumerate(pulse_ends):
            if pulse_end > pulse_start:
                pulse_fall_time = fall_times[i]
                break
        if not pulse_fall_time:
            continue
        # Average the power over the pulse
        power = np.average(data_y[pulse_start: pulse_end])
        new_pulse = Pulse(
            data_x[pulse_start],
            data_x[pulse_end] - data_x[pulse_start],
            power,
            data_x[pulse_start] - data_x[pulse_rise_time],
            data_x[pulse_fall_time] - data_x[pulse_end]
        )
        pulses.append(new_pulse)
    return pulses


def _main():
    size = int(2 ** 12)
    pulse_count = 10
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=46)

    pulses = [
        Pulse(
            round(rng.random() * 0.95, 4),
            round(rng.random() * 0.05, 4),
            round(rng.random() * 0.5 + 0.5, 4),
            round(rng.random() * 0.01 + 0.01, 4),
            round(rng.random() * 0.01 + 0.01, 4)
        ) for _ in range(pulse_count)
    ]
    datax, datay = make_data(pulses, 1.0, size, rng, 0.02)

    s = time.perf_counter()
    pulses_out = find_pulses(datax, datay, 0.01)
    e = time.perf_counter() - s

    print(f'\nRun time: {e * 1e3:.3f} ms\n')
    print('Real pulse values:')
    [print('    ', x) for x in sorted(pulses, key=lambda x: x.t)]
    print('Estimated pulses:')
    [print('    ', x) for x in sorted(pulses_out, key=lambda x: x.t)]
    table_rows = []
    used_pulses = set()
    for pulse in sorted(pulses, key=lambda x: x.t):
        best_index = np.argmin([np.abs(pulsex.t - pulse.t) for pulsex in pulses_out])
        best_pulse = pulses_out[best_index]
        used_pulses.add(best_index)
        diff_fracs = pulse.diff_frac(best_pulse)
        table_rows.append(diff_fracs)
    for i, pulse in enumerate(pulses_out):
        if i not in used_pulses:
            print('Unused pulse: ', pulse)
    display_labels = ['pulse number', 't', 'pw', 'power', 'rise time', 'fall time']
    field_width = 16
    print()
    print('Percent errors (negative indicate estimate is lower than actual)')
    print(''.join([f'{dl:>{field_width}}' for dl in display_labels]))
    for i, table_row in enumerate(table_rows):
        print(f'{i:>{field_width}}' + ''.join([f'{field * 100:> {field_width}.2f}' for field in table_row]))

    plt.plot([datax[0], datax[-1]], [-0.2] * 2, '-', color='#AAAAAA')
    for show_level, pulse_data in [(-0.15, pulses), (-0.28, pulses_out)]:
        for i, pulse in enumerate(sorted(pulse_data, key=lambda x: x.t)):
            level = [show_level + (i % 2) * .03] * 2
            plt.plot([pulse.t - pulse.rise_time, pulse.t], level, '-g', linewidth=3)
            plt.plot([pulse.t, pulse.t + pulse.pw], level, '-k', linewidth=3)
            plt.plot([pulse.t + pulse.pw, pulse.t + pulse.pw + pulse.fall_time], level, '-r', linewidth=3)

    patch0 = matplotlib.patches.Patch(color='b', label='Sample data')
    patch1 = matplotlib.patches.Patch(color='g', label='Rising edge')
    patch2 = matplotlib.patches.Patch(color='k', label='Pulse at full power')
    patch3 = matplotlib.patches.Patch(color='r', label='Falling edge')
    patch4 = matplotlib.patches.Patch(color='w', label='Above grey line is truth')
    patch5 = matplotlib.patches.Patch(color='w', label='Below grey line is estimate')
    plt.legend(handles=[patch0, patch1, patch2, patch3, patch4, patch5], loc='upper left')
    plt.plot(datax, datay)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()


Running that code I get the following output:
Run time: 26.168 ms

Real pulse values:
     Pulse(t=0.0807, pw=0.0315, power=0.8878, rise_time=0.0151, fall_time=0.0175)
     Pulse(t=0.2391, pw=0.0421, power=0.5035, rise_time=0.0118, fall_time=0.0164)
     Pulse(t=0.4258, pw=0.0096, power=0.7318, rise_time=0.0113, fall_time=0.0145)
     Pulse(t=0.4548, pw=0.0251, power=0.8405, rise_time=0.0106, fall_time=0.0173)
     Pulse(t=0.6206, pw=0.045, power=0.811, rise_time=0.0199, fall_time=0.015)
     Pulse(t=0.6845, pw=0.0022, power=0.6297, rise_time=0.0117, fall_time=0.0155)
     Pulse(t=0.7343, pw=0.0033, power=0.5525, rise_time=0.0139, fall_time=0.0133)
     Pulse(t=0.8365, pw=0.025, power=0.8975, rise_time=0.0106, fall_time=0.0173)
     Pulse(t=0.8603, pw=0.0039, power=0.6363, rise_time=0.0162, fall_time=0.0193)
     Pulse(t=0.9089, pw=0.0255, power=0.7247, rise_time=0.0148, fall_time=0.0125)
Estimated pulses:
     Pulse(t=0.07838827838827839, pw=0.03614163614163614, power=0.8968497048801296, rise_time=0.012942612942612938, fall_time=0.0153846153846154)
     Pulse(t=0.23736263736263735, pw=0.04664224664224664, power=0.5130991881085685, rise_time=0.010012210012210004, fall_time=0.013675213675213682)
     Pulse(t=0.4244200244200244, pw=0.012210012210012222, power=0.7412289812489139, rise_time=0.010012210012209977, fall_time=0.007081807081807057)
     Pulse(t=0.4547008547008547, pw=0.02783882783882785, power=0.8492026244322083, rise_time=0.010500610500610519, fall_time=0.014896214896214899)
     Pulse(t=0.6175824175824176, pw=0.04761904761904756, power=0.8208984071590608, rise_time=0.0168498168498169, fall_time=0.007570207570207654)
     Pulse(t=0.6847374847374847, pw=0.00366300366300365, power=0.6396379252906029, rise_time=0.0017094017094017033, fall_time=0.014407814407814357)
     Pulse(t=0.7328449328449328, pw=0.007081807081807168, power=0.558567263040093, rise_time=0.01245421245421241, fall_time=0.01172161172161168)
     Pulse(t=0.8354090354090354, pw=0.029548229548229554, power=1.2368971895123717, rise_time=0.009523809523809601, fall_time=0.01831501831501825)
     Pulse(t=0.8581196581196581, pw=0.006837606837606924, power=1.5380436954887393, rise_time=0.01391941391941387, fall_time=0.01831501831501825)
     Pulse(t=0.9074481074481074, pw=0.02857142857142858, power=0.7343365142142995, rise_time=0.013431013431013383, fall_time=0.010744810744810707)

Percent errors (negative indicate estimate is lower than actual)
    pulse number               t              pw           power       rise time       fall time
               0           -7.34           14.74            1.02          -14.29          -12.09
               1           -4.13           10.79            1.91          -15.15          -16.61
               2          -14.37           27.19            1.29          -11.40          -51.16
               3           -0.40           10.91            1.04           -0.94          -13.89
               4           -6.71            5.82            1.22          -15.33          -49.53
               5           10.79           66.50            1.58          -85.39           -7.05
               6          -44.09          114.60            1.10          -10.40          -11.87
               7           -4.36           18.19           37.82          -10.15            5.87
               8          -55.91           75.32          141.72          -14.08           -5.10
               9           -5.69           12.04            1.33           -9.25          -14.04



Looking at the bars below the signal, you can see the pulses are quite close to the truth data when the pulses have good isolation, and can be quite poor when the pulses are on top of each other. Depending on your pulse shape, it may perform better or much worse, but should do decently on pulses with good isolation. It has some inherent noise resistance, but as noise increases it may perform much worse, though significant improvements are possible with some pre-filtering.

I know there is a lot here, so feel free to ask any questions and I will do my best to answer them.

This is amazing, great work! I have a small question: can you please let me know what versions of the libraries you are using and which OS? Thank you so much!

@TinoD For those results I used
Windows 10 -
Python 3.11.8 -
numpy 1.26.4 -
scipy 1.12.0
Let me know if you have any questions
